# How can I monitor in HTML the live data from a PHP file that updates every 3 seconds with data coming from a SQL DB?

Tags: php, html, json, ajax, monitoring

I am trying to display an HTML file that shows a Gauge from google charts that updates every 3 seconds with the new data that a PHP file is grabbing from a SQL DB. there is no way that I can make the gauge to show the parameters from the PHP file. It only remains in the original position.

This is my JS and HTML code:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['gauge']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var air = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Air Tº', 0],
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 800,
    height: 240,
    redFrom: 480,
    redTo: 580,
    yellowFrom: 350,
    yellowTo: 480,
    minorTicks: 5,
    min: 0,
    max: 580
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('air'));

  chart.draw(air, options);

  setInterval(function() {
    var JSON = $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/datos.php?q=1",
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false
    }).responseText;
    var Respuesta = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON);

    data.setValue(0, 1, Respuesta[0].Air);
    chart.draw(air, options);
  }, 1300);

}
```

```html
<title>Engine Parameters Live Monitoring</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

  <div id="air"></div>
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=monitoring;host=127.0.0.1:3307","root","");
switch($_GET['q']){
        // Get last datapoint
        case 1:
            $statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT id, Air, Process, RPMspeed, Torque, Wear FROM parameters ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1");
            $statement->execute();
            $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $json=json_encode($results);
            echo $json;
        break; 
        // Get all datapoints
        default:
            
            $statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT id, Air, Process, RPMspeed, Torque, Wear FROM parameters ORDER BY id ASC");
            $statement->execute();
            $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $json=json_encode($results);
            echo $json;
        break;

}
?>
```

[PHP results grabbed automatically from DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH0wv.png)
[Gauge that needs to be updated automatically every 3 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiJu0.png)

I know there is some JSON and AJAX in my code, I really don't know about these languages. If someone could help me I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: _but it is throwing an error_ Well now is the time to start learning. AJAX is not a programming language. AJAX just uses a combination of:

    A browser built-in XMLHttpRequest object (to request data from a web server)
    JavaScript and HTML DOM (to display or use the data)

Comment: you dont appear to update the data that is used to render the chart.  Within the ajax callback you should update that`air` or datatable before calling `draw`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius it seems that is exactly what they do here: `data.setValue(0, 1, Respuesta[0].Air);`

Comment: but where is data defined and used?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should send a request (ajax request) to the php file which you want to claim data by this code

```
function claim_data() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "my_php_destination.php", false);
  xhttp.send();
  var my_json = xhttp.responseText;
}
```

this varieble (my_json) will be same thing with $json in your php file
then if you want to update your data every 3000 milliseconds then you should do this ajax request in an interval like this

```
setInterval(function (claim_data()) {}, 3000);
```